# FOSJsRoutingBundle dump with baseurl

Tags: symfony-3.3, fosjsroutingbundle

I use

`php bin/console fos:js-routing:dump -e=prod --target="web/js/fos_js_routes.prod.js"`

to dump all routes, but the problem is my production symfony not in root url.

I mean, it place in `https://myshop.com/symfonyapp` and all generated route dont have `/symfonyapp`

for example `homepage` to be `/` and what I expect is `/symfonyapp/`

how to set baseurl to dump all route?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup this variable in the config file:

```
// config/packages/fos_js_routing.yaml

fos_js_routing:
    request_context_base_url: 'symfonyapp/'
```